# How to implement Server side paging in Client side Kendo UI grid in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Can anyone tell me how can I implement server-side paging with client-side Kendo UI Grid?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

> UPDATE: We have [released](http://blogs.telerik.com/kendoui/posts/14-01-02/kendo-ui-open-sources-dynamic-linq-helpers) an open source .NET library which makes paging, sorting an filtering a lot easier.

The grid will send the current `pageSize` and `skip` once you set `serverPaging` to `true`. On the server side you should page your data using the provided info and return it together with the total number of items. Here is a code snippet:

#### Action

```
public ActionResult Products(int pageSize, int skip) 
{
     using (var northwind = new NorthwindDataContext())
     {
        var products = northwind.Products;
        // Get the total number of records - needed for paging
        var total = products.Count();

        // Page the data
        var data = products.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();

        // Return as JSON - the Kendo Grid will use the response
        return Json(new { total = total, data = data });
     }
}
```

#### View

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
               url: "home/products",
               dataType: "json",
               type: "POST"
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: "data", // records are returned in the "data" field of the response
            total: "total" // total number of records is in the "total" field of the response
        },
        serverPaging: true // enable server paging
    }
});
```

### Reference

#### Paging with LINQ

- [Take() and Skip()](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/1/justlearned/0/tips/9313/take-and-skip-methods-makes-paging-simplified-in-linq.aspx)

#### DataSource configuration settings

- [serverPaging](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-serverPaging)
- [schema.data](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.data)
- [schema.total](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.total)

Comment: Can you please post the MVC4 wrapper approach for this?

Comment: The MVC wrapper does this automatically when the ToDataSourceResult extension method is used. Here are the docs: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/ajax-binding

Comment: Suppose I am using a stored procedure instead of any ORM. How can we pass the page number to the stored procedure? And how can we set the total?

Comment: Check the custom binding help topic: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/custom-binding

Comment: Are we forced to request the total number of rows in every query we send for paging ? Can we set the total once and never think about that after that ?

Comment: And why POST ? Why not GET ?

Comment: POST is almost always used when you call a method that returns a JSON response, to prevent CSRF attacks. By default, MVC won't even let you create a GET that returns JSON - it will give you an error. Here's an explanation http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx/

Comment: @NibblyPig According to OWASP, using POST by itself doesn't prevent CSRF attacks.  It's harder to do, but its still possible.  ["Applications can be developed to only accept POST requests for the execution of business logic. The misconception is that since the attacker cannot construct a malicious link, a CSRF attack cannot be executed. Unfortunately, this logic is incorrect."](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF))

Comment: MVC will stop you doing a cross-domain post by sending the appropriate Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the client's browser. So either the dev would have to override this default behaviour or the client's browser would have to be compromised.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer does not have a UI solution; only provides a jQuery answer. In case it helps anyone else, here is the solution that worked for our kendo grid in UI:

code snippet of Controller

```
        DataSourceResult result = new DataSourceResult()
        {
            Data = dataSet,
            Total = recordCount
        };

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

code snippet of View

```
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource                
            .Ajax()
            .Read(read => read.Action("*<our method>*", "*<our controller>*")
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement server pagination, correct format should be return from server. For server side paging JSON format will be something like below JSON:-

```
{ "mytotal":1069, "mydata": [{ ProductID : 1, ProductName : "Chai"}, { ProductID : 2, ProductName : "Chang" }]}
```

Tell to kendo grid pick total number of records from mytotal object and data rows from mydata in schema

```
schema: {
    data: "mydata"
    total: "mytotal" // total is returned in the "total" field of the response
  }
```

Check detail example [here](http://www.letmeknows.com/2017/04/24/implement-serverpagination-in-kendo-grid-jquery-required-json-string/)