# Pagination on Kendo UI Grid is not working

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm displaying a grid with remote data, if I don't add pagination the full set of data is displayed, of course this is not desired.

The following is the code I'm using to display data on a grid:

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:81/SismosService.svc/usuario/index",
            dataType: "json"
        }
    },
    schema: {
        data: "Response"
    },
    pageSize: 5
});
$("#usuariosGrid").kendoGrid({
    pageable: {
        refresh: true
    },
    columns: [
        { field: "UsuarioId", title: "ID", width: "100px" },
        { field: "Nombre", title: "Nombre", width: "100px" },
        { field: "ApellidoP", title: "Apellido Paterno", width: "100px" },
        { field: "ApellidoM", title: "Apellido Materno", width: "100px" },
        { command: [{ text: "Editar", click: editFunction }, { text: "Eliminar", click: deleteFunction }], title: " ", width: "200px" }
    ],
    dataSource: ds
});
```

This renders a grid with 5 items on it, but that's it, I can't navigate through the rest of the entries. The number of pages and items to display is marked as zero, disabling the navigation controls.

Am I missing something in my cofiguration? Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When paging is done in the server (check [serverpaging](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#serverpaging-booleandefault)), you need to return the total number of records. See [`total`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#schematotal-functionstring) for information.

Comment: I changed my code to look like [this](http://pastebin.com/g9rzfidX), the number of pages is correct and the navigation buttons are working, but it is showing all of the entries in the same page all the time. Am I missing something else?

Comment: When doing `serverPaging` the server is responsible of pagination so it should only send `pageSize` records. Is your server returning only the number of records specified in `pageSize`?

Comment: I think I'm misinterpreted something, I thought that pageSize was referring to the amount of entries per page rendered in the grid. I thought that if the server returned 20 entries and the pageSize defined in the data source was 5, then I would render 4 pages with 5 entries each in the grid. But from what you're telling me, I'm guessing the pageSize is a parameter sent to the server to return 2 pages of entries? If that's the case, my server doesn't have an endpoint that receives such parameter. If my server returns _n_ entries, how can I render those entries in _m_ pages?

Comment: If you want to display groups of 5 entries per page BUT receiving all data from the server, then you should specify `serverPaging` to false.

Comment: ok, so I had to specify the pageSize, the total and set serverPaging to false. Now it works. Thanks.

Comment: Worked when i set dataSource to  .ServerOperation(false);

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue because I misunderstood serverPaging. If you set serverPaging to true, you also have to modify what the server returns.

Previously, I had the server returning all of the data. To fix this, I used `ToDataSourceResult` to modify what my server returns.

See: 
[How to implement Server side paging in Client side Kendo UI grid in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928744/how-to-implement-server-side-paging-in-client-side-kendo-ui-grid-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

spend a day on this minor issue, all you have to do is return the total number of records, if your service doesn't return the total number of records, do the following

```
schema: {
        data: "Response"
    },

total: function(response)
      {
        return response."your method name".length;
      }
```