# Kendo UI: lazy binding for Kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui

Can any one please let me know how can I load first 5000 rows into kendo grid and then load the remaining rows on page selects. I have 50000 rows to load and the page with kendo grid is loading pretty slow. So I want to use lazy loading approach..like loadin gthe first 5000 and then load the next rows in 1000's on page button clicks.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can either enable [virtual scrolling](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/virtualization-local-data.html) or implement [server paging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12929274/10141).

Comment: I am now trying to load the kendo grid datasource from another aspx page. i am able to get the data from aspx page (I can see it in response block of chrome), but am unable to add it to the kendo grid

Comment: A demo for virtual scrollable can be found here http://kendogridbinderex.apphb.com/OU/VirtualScrollable