# How to do Kendo grid column optimization

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-grid

Am using kendo grid , I need to do optimization for grid columns. Am doing Optimization now, but its not effective. Am looping on each `td` of each `tr` and calculating the width of `td` and if it is max width then am setting the width to column. So, if i have more number of records in the grid(ex:20000), then its taking lot time to calculate. Is there any other way to approach my requirement.

Comment: Any examples of what you have done?

Comment: @fuyushimoya I didnt prepare any example. Simply just looping on html table tr's and then looping on td's of each tr.

Comment: Then, whats the `max width`, is it means the the `td`'s width is the largest among other `td`s

Comment: bind grid to remote data, not local binding so you will work on first 10 rows (if paging is enabled) not on 20000 and i recommend this approach in columns widths http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/walkthrough#column-widths if u want auto-sized columns

Comment: @TarekNajem there is a page size change option. So we can change the page size. In that case am facing problem. Unfortunately I Can not remove the page size Option.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it seems you are dealing with bulk of data which is taking considerable load time and you want to reduce it. So here I would recommend you to go for Server side Pagination. Server pagination is very effective and reduce load time. It loads data in chunks, I believe it would help you, below are some links which can help you out :

[How to implement Server side paging in Client side Kendo UI grid in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928744/how-to-implement-server-side-paging-in-client-side-kendo-ui-grid-in-asp-net-mvc)

https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-get-the-best-grid-performance